# Regarding struct hack using int type

Tags: c, struct

Can we do struct hack(using int type) as below

```
struct node{
   int i;
   struct node *next;
   int p[0];
}

int main(){
   struct node *n = // is this the correct hack i.e. p[10]?
      malloc(sizeof(struct node) + sizeof(int) * 10);
}
```

Also using int type with size 1

```
struct node{
   int i;
   struct node *next;
   int p[1];
}

int main(){
   struct node *n = // is this a correct hack i.e. p[10]?
      malloc(sizeof(struct node) + sizeof(int) * 10);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former is the struct hack as used in c89. Validity of this construct has always been questionable.

The latter is a GNU struct hack, it makes use of a GNU extension and is not valid C.

The correct way to have a structures whose size could vary at run time is to use the c99 *flexible array member* feature.

```
struct node{
    int i;
    struct node *next;
    int p[];
}

int main(void)
{
     struct node *n = malloc(sizeof (struct node) + sizeof (int) * 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used the same name twice. You will have to choose a different one.
It is correct, apart from not using the correct syntax.

Should be `[]` not `[1]` or `[0]`, this way the code is not a "hack", but is legal from c99 onward, also called flexible array members.

```
struct node{
    int i;
    struct node *next;
    int n[];
} ;
```